# JavaFX: Nested for loops for placing rectangles isn't working

Tags: java, javafx, iteration, javafx-8, nested-loops

I am trying to create a checkerboard by using for loops and creating different colored rectangles. I'm using two nested for loops: the 1st one that takes care of all rows starting with a black square and the 2nd one that takes care of all rows starting with a red square. I have a list of x coordinates and two separate lists for y coordinates: y1coords being all y coordinates that correspond to a row starting with a black square and y2coords being all y coordinates that correspond to a row starting with a red square.

```
//Nested for loop for every row starting with a black square
List<Double> y1coords = Arrays.asList(0.0,150.0,300.0,450.0);
List<Double> xcoords = Arrays.asList(0.0,75.0,150.0,225.0,300.0,375.0,450.0,525.0);
for (int j=0; j<y1coords.size(); j++)
{
  for (int i=0; i<xcoords.size(); i++)
  {
    if (xcoords.get(i)%2 == 0)
    {
      Rectangle square = new Rectangle(75,75,Color.BLACK);
      square.setX(xcoords.get(i));
      square.setY(y1coords.get(j));
      root.getChildren().add(square);
    }
    else
    {
      Rectangle square = new Rectangle(75,75,Color.RED);
      square.setX(xcoords.get(i));
      square.setY(y1coords.get(j));
      root.getChildren().add(square);
    }
  }
}
//Nested for loop for every row starting with a red square
List<Double> y2coords = Arrays.asList(75.0,225.0,375.0,525.0);
for (int j=0; j<y2coords.size(); j++)
{
  for (int i=0; i<xcoords.size(); i++)
  {
    if (xcoords.get(i)%2 != 0)
    {
      Rectangle square = new Rectangle(75,75,Color.BLACK);
      square.setX(xcoords.get(i));
      square.setX(y2coords.get(j));
      root.getChildren().add(square);
    }
    else
    {
      Rectangle square = new Rectangle(75,75,Color.RED);
      square.setX(xcoords.get(i));
      square.setX(y2coords.get(j));
      root.getChildren().add(square);
    }
  }
}
```

I want this to create a nice looking checkerboard, but it keeps giving me the first row completely black and doesn't do any of the rows starting with a red square. Visit https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D6szyy7X4AEMGtk.jpg:large to see what I mean.

Comment: What is the type of `root`? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you illustrate.

Comment: In your second looping you're setting `setX` twice, instead of `setX and setY`.

Comment: Why are there 2 lists necessary? Why do you check the coordinates modulo 2 instead of the sum of the indices modulo 2? Why doing the same things in both blocks of the `if`/`else` instead of minimizing the amount of code in those blocks and thus maximizing the code shared between both cases? `Rectangle square = new Rectangle(75, 75, (i+j) % 2 == 0 ? Color.BLACK : Color.RED); square.setX(...); ...`

Comment: Thanks everyone, fortunately, shortly after I posted this, I created the board using a much more simple approach and condensed a lot of code that way.

Comment: @trashgod it was a Group type, sorry about the confusion this is the first question i ever posted so i'm pretty new to this

Comment: @kendavidson wow i wish i woulda noticed that lol, thanks!

Comment: We've all done it.  Ps.  I fully agree with fabian's comment.

Answer (score 0):

edit your code in the second nested for loops

from

```
square.setX(y2coords.get(j));
```

to

```
square.setY(y2coords.get(j));
```

the final result is

```
                if (xcoords.get(i) % 2 != 0) {
                    Rectangle square = new Rectangle(75, 75, Color.BLACK);
                    square.setX(xcoords.get(i));
       /*here*/     square.setY(y2coords.get(j));
                    root.getChildren().add(square);
                } else {
                    Rectangle square = new Rectangle(75, 75, Color.RED);
                    square.setX(xcoords.get(i));
     /*and here*/   square.setY(y2coords.get(j));
                    root.getChildren().add(square);
                }
```